# Getting error while consuming the WCF service in MAUI using emulator

Tags: maui

I have tried to consume my wcf service in MAUI application, but I am getting this below error while running the application via emulator.

Error Details:
System.Net.WebException Message=java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Already I have followed the steps from below URL's, but it doesn't work. My application is based on MAUI framework.

[Android - Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106525/android-caused-by-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor)

[Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection)

Any solution for this?

Regards,
Panjanatham

Comment: please [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Trust+anchor+for+certification+path+not+found.%22+site:stackoverflow.com) before posting

Comment: Hi,
Already I have followed the steps from below URL's, but it doesn't work. My application is based on MAUI framework.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106525/android-caused-by-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection

Comment: Could you please provide the full error log of this problem?